# How to test which version of Service Fabric Runtime is installed

Tags: windows-server-2016, azure-service-fabric

Anyone know how to test that the right version of service fabric is installed.

I want to add a section to my build server configuration to ensure that the service fabric cmdlets are installed and can be used by our build processes.

I want to get this exe installed 
[https://download.microsoft.com/dow
nload/1/A/A/1AA062F9-0E1D-40E9-
BD4F6F12ABB71083/MicrosoftServiceFabri
c.6.3.176.9494.exe](https://download.microsoft.com/dow%20nload/1/A/A/1AA062F9-0E1D-40E9-%20BD4F6F12ABB71083/MicrosoftServiceFabri%20c.6.3.176.9494.exe) on windows 2016 boxes if it is not already there.

I have had a look at

```
get-wmiObject -class Win32_Product
```

But it doesn't seem to be showing up there, is it a windows update or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to identify the Current installed version:

1. Registry entry

   - Open the Registry Editor (regedit)
   - Navigate to: `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Service Fabric`
   - Find the key: `FabricVersion`
   - You can also do it via powershell: `Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Service Fabric\' -Name FabricVersion`
2. Binaries Version

   - Go to the runtime installation folder, something like this: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\`
   - Find the application `FabricHost.exe` and click properties, go to the tab details, the version will be listed there
3. Installed applications

   - Goto Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features
   - Search in the List for 'Fabric' and select 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric'
   - In the details will show the app version
4. Service Fabric Explorer

   - Open the service fabric explorer
   - Go to the list of node and select one
   - Navigate to the tab `Details`
   - Find the attribute `Code Version`
   - You can also to this approach via:

     - System > fabric:/System/ClusterManagerService > Details > `Manifest Version`

Comment: Thanks for the feed back.
I should have mentioned that most of the boxes that need to be configured are core and have no UI, but even if they did I still need to do this through a script.
The registry option could work:
Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Service Fabric\' -Name FabricVersion

Answer (score 0):

**BELOW IS INCORRECT SEE Diego comment**

So there seems to be a powershell command that is installed as part of the runtime that answers this question.

```
(Get-Module -ListAvailable ServiceFabric) -ne $null -and (Get-ServiceFabricRuntimeSupportedVersion -Latest).Version -eq "6.3.176.9494"
```

This will get me going for now, although if anyone has any better suggestions please let me know. cheers.

**BEST SOLUTION SO FAR thanks to Diego**

```
(Test-Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Service Fabric\') -and (Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Service Fabric\' -Name FabricVersion) -eq "6.3.176.9494"
```

Comment: This does not provide the answer for your question. `Get-ServiceFabricRuntimeSupportedVersion` gets the details about all currently supported service fabric runtime versions for standalone deployments. currently supported means, the versions that still receive fixes from SF team.

Comment: Ahh good to know, guess I will switch to the registry key approach, thanks for the help. can you edit your answer to have the Get-ItemPropertyValue command as the number 1 option and I will accept that as the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Via (modern) C# API (QueryManager):

```
using FabricClient fabClient = new FabricClient();
var x = await fabClient.QueryManager.GetNodeListAsync("SFRole0_0");
string version = x[0].CodeVersion;
```

Via Powershell:

```
Get-ServiceFabricNode -NodeName SFRole0_0 | Select CodeVersion
```